# converting month number to date using KornShell

Tags: shell, date, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to convert month number to name, but it is giving output as current month instead of the date given in the variable.

**KornShell (ksh) Code:**

```
datep= 2013-10-22
echo $datep |printf "%(%B)T\n"
```

Comment: No (unquoted) space is allowed following the equal sign: use `datep=2013-10-22`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$ datep="2013-10-22"
$ date -d"$datep" "+%B"
October
```

As per `man date`,

> **-d, --date=STRING**
>
> display time described by STRING, not 'now'

So we get:

```
$ date -d"$datep"
Tue Oct 22 00:00:00 CEST 2013
```

Then you say you want the `%B`, that is, also from `man date`:

> **%B**
>
> locale's full month name (e.g., January)

So it is just a matter of using the format at the end of the string.

Other examples:

```
$ date -d"$datep" "+%Y" #year
2013
$ date -d"$datep" "+%F" #date
2013-10-22
$ date -d"$datep" "+%T" #time (if not given, gets the default)
00:00:00
```

Comment: thanks for the answer 
can you just explain in brief how it worked

Comment: Uhms, interesting @chepner . I guess I should install `ksh` in my machine to do some tests.

Comment: I like to think of it as the forgotten shell :). It's got some features that still haven't been picked up by `bash` (or even `zsh`, amazingly).

Comment: export month_end_date=`tail -1 month_end_dt.txt`
export month=`printf "%(%B)T\n" "$month_end_date"`

i have a date in the `month_end_dt.txt` file and assigning the date to `month_end_date` parameter.
i wanted to make that as global variable which will used across many scripts so exporting the month name into a variable `month`

i am getting an error 
main.ksh[7]: export: %(%B)T\n: is not an identifier

Comment: @user2014896 to evaluate a command, do `var=$(command)`. In your case, `end_date=$(tail -1 ...)`. Regarding the rest, it is better if you update your answer or ask a new one. In comments it is difficult to check code.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't read from standard input, so it is assuming today's date as the default argument for the `%T` format; you need to provide the date as an argument instead.

```
printf "%(%B)T\n" "$datep"
```

Comment: export month_end_date=`tail -1 month_end_dt.txt`


export month=`printf "%(%B)T\n" "$month_end_date"`



i have a date in the `month_end_dt.txt` file and assigning the date to `month_end_date` parameter.
i wanted to make that as global variable which will used across many scripts so exporting the month name into a variable `month`



i am getting an error 


main.ksh[7]: export: %(%B)T\n: is not an identifier

Comment: You need to capture the output of the `printf` first: `export WHATEVER=$(printf "%(%B)T\n" "$datep")`